# How to adjust script to copy all files from current month?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can somebody help me to adjust this script in a way that all files from the current month will be copied?

At the moment it will copy all files older than 3 days and this will not work for us.

Within a month period we create a random number of files at `\\sharename\folder\source`.

Here is the batch code:

```
set datetimef=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2% 
if not exist "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%" mkdir "\\sharename\folder \%datetimef%" 
forfiles -p "\\sharename\folder\source" -s -m *.xml /D -3 /C "cmd /c copy @file "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%"
```

And it seems to work as designed.

Comment: I assume the `/D -3` is the previous 3 days... try just changing that to `/D -30` to do the last 30 days?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The last 30 days are not always in the same month !

Comment: Ah, I see, I must have read the request wrong. Parse the current day from the date, and do a `/D -%DAY%` so it looks back however many days for whatever the current day is?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: How would this look like in the script ?
SachaDee: exactly thats my problem, i can't use a fixed number of days..

Answer (score 1):

The commented batch code below copies all files last modified this month using command [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) (Microsoft article).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "SharedFolder=\\sharename\folder"

rem Get year and month from environment variable DATE in format yyyy-mm.
rem It is required for this simple method that environment variable DATE
rem contains the date in format dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy with or without
rem weekday at beginning. If the format of the date string output with
rem echo %DATE% in a command prompt window is different, the line below
rem must be adapted, or the two commented lines with command wmic are
rem used because wmic returns the current date in a format independent
rem on Windows region and language settings.

set "YearMonth=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-7,2%"
rem for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS get localdatetime /VALUE') do set LocalDateTime=%%T
rem set "YearMonth=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%

rem Define source and target folder.
set "TargetFolder=%SharedFolder%\%YearMonth%"
set "SourceFolder=%SharedFolder%\source"

rem Create the target folder if not already existing and verify the
rem successful creation of target folder before copying the files.

if not exist "%TargetFolder%\*" (
    mkdir "%TargetFolder%"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Error detected by %~f0:
        echo.
        echo Failed to create folder %TargetFolder%
        echo.
        echo Check availability of server and access permissions on share.
        echo.
        pause
        endlocal
        goto :EOF
    )
)

rem Define date used below on command XCOPY in format mm-dd-yyyy.
set "XcopyDate=%YearMonth:~5,2%-01-%YearMonth:~0,4%

rem Copy all files last modified this month with archive attribute set.
rem The archive attribute is removed after copying on source file to prevent
rem one more copying operation of same file if this batch file is executed
rem once more this month and source file was not modified since last run.

xcopy "%SourceFolder%\*" "%TargetFolder%\" /C /D:%XcopyDate% /H /I /K /M /Q /R /Y

endlocal
```

You might append on command line with [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (SS64 article) also the options `/V` and `/Z`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

---

I offer also a second version making this task the hard way without using **xcopy** with parameter `/D`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SharedFolder=\\sharename\folder"

rem Get year and month from environment variable DATE in format yyyy-mm.
rem It is required for this simple method that environment variable DATE
rem contains the date in format dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy with or without
rem weekday at beginning. If the format of the date string output with
rem echo %DATE% in a command prompt window is different, the line below
rem must be adapted, or the two commented lines with command wmic are
rem used because wmic returns the current date in a format independent
rem on Windows region and language settings.

set "YearMonth=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-7,2%"
rem for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS get localdatetime /VALUE') do set LocalDateTime=%%T
rem set "YearMonth=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%

rem Define source and target folder.
set "TargetFolder=%SharedFolder%\%YearMonth%"
set "SourceFolder=%SharedFolder%\source"

rem Create the target folder if not already existing and verify the
rem successful creation of target folder before processing the files.

if not exist "%TargetFolder%\*" (
    mkdir "%TargetFolder%"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Error detected by %~f0:
        echo.
        echo Failed to create folder %TargetFolder%
        echo.
        echo Check availability of server and access permissions on share.
        echo.
        pause
        endlocal
        goto :EOF
    )
)

rem Define and initialize two counters. First one counts how many files
rem are processed successfully and second one counts how many files
rem found to process. Finally those two counts should be always equal.

set "CountProcessed=0"
set "CountTotal=0"

rem Use command DIR to get just the names of all files in source folder
rem without path sorted reverse according to last modification date, i.e.
rem file modified last being returned first and oldest modified file being
rem at end of list.

rem For each file name returned by command DIR get last modification time.
rem It is necessary here to use command FOR for this task as DIR without
rem parameter /S returns just the file name and first FOR would not be
rem able to determine location of file to get last modification time if
rem the source folder is not the current folder which is not the case here.

rem Again it is important to know the format of last modification date/time
rem which depends on Windows region and language settings to correct extract
rem just year and month with a hyphen between to compare with year and month
rem of current date. The last modification time string must start with the
rem date in format dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy to use the code below as is.

rem On first file with a last modification year and month not matching
rem current year and month, the FOR loop processing the file names is
rem exited with a jump to label below the FOR loop as now all other files
rem in list should be outside of current month. This early loop exit could
rem result in a wrong behavior if a file has a last modification date in
rem future in comparison to current date.

rem Copying a file is done using command COPY. This command has some
rem limitations like not overwriting read-only files in target folder.
rem Success on copying the file is evaluated by the batch script. It
rem would be also possible to use XCOPY or ROBOCOPY with the appropriate
rem parameters to copy also hidden or read-only files if this is necessary.

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /O-D /TW "%SourceFolder%\*" 2^>nul') do (

    for %%F in ("%SourceFolder%\%%I") do set "LastModification=%%~tF"

    if not "!LastModification:~6,4!-!LastModification:~3,2!" == "%YearMonth%" goto ProcessingDone

    set /A CountTotal+=1
    copy /B /Y "%SourceFolder%\%%I" "%TargetFolder%" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        set /A CountProcessed+=1
    ) else (
        echo Failed to copy file %%I
    )
)

:ProcessingDone
if "%CountTotal%" == "1" (
    set "PluralTotal="
) else (
    set "PluralTotal=s"
)
if "%CountProcessed%" == "1" (
    set "PluralProcessed="
) else (
    set "PluralProcessed=s"
)
echo.
echo Processed %CountProcessed% file%PluralProcessed% of total %CountTotal% file%PluralTotal% for %YearMonth%.
endlocal
```

This batch code could be used to move, modify or delete all files last modified this month by searching not case sensitive for `copy`, replace the command by something different and adapt the comments and output messages.